# Cannot update text in GUI as the scripts within a function get run completely

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a code which I am providing here, which gets displayed by default in the tkinter GUI that I have created. This basically displays whether the scripts within a function get run completely or not. When the scripts get run successfully, the text is supposed to get updated, which is happening, but not sequentially, meaning, both the texts are getting updated only after both the scripts are run completely. I want them to update sequentially, which I am not able to do now. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

```
a = tk.Label(main_gui, text="Image_files script run? NO", fg = "yellow", bg = "black", font='Ariel 13 bold')
a.pack()
a.place(x=20, y=350)

b = tk.Label(main_gui, text="Image_stack script run? NO", fg = "yellow", bg = "black", font='Ariel 13 bold')
b.pack()
b.place(x=20, y=370)
```

The function is this:

```
def df(dd):
    import df
    df.func3(dd)    
    a.config(text="Image_files script run? YES", fg = "black", bg = "yellow")

    import figures_for_df
    figures_for_df.func4(dd)
    b.config(text="Image_stack script run? YES", fg = "black", bg = "yellow")
```

Comment: What is `df`, `figures_for_df`

Comment: @CoolCloud: They are python scripts that I want to execute on a button press, based on a GUI

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it out. I needed to use the `update()` command. Here is the code:

```
def df(dd):
    import df
    df.func3(dd)    
    a.config(text="Image_files script run? YES", fg = "black", bg = "yellow")
    main_gui.update()

    import figures_for_df
    figures_for_df.func4(dd)
    b.config(text="Image_stack script run? YES", fg = "black", bg = "yellow")
```

Where, main_gui is:

```
main_gui = tk.Tk()
main_gui.title("Widefield Analysis")
main_gui.geometry("550x550")
```